# For someone who buys a ticket, what is the expected value?

Tags: probability

I am posting my question and answer. Can't seem to figure out any of these problems (the program won't accept my answers). My tutor is busy and can't help me.

> Tickets for a raffle cost $\$13$. There were $739$ tickets sold. One ticket will be randomly selected as the winner, and that person wins $\$1700$ and also the person is given back the cost of the ticket. For someone who buys a ticket, what is the Expected Value (the mean of the distribution)?
>   If the Expected Value is negative, be sure to include the "-" sign with the answer. Express the answer rounded to two decimal places.

**MY ANSWER**
$-10.66$ is this right or wrong?
How I got my answer:
$$-13(738/739) + 1713(1/739)$$

Comment: The cost of the ticket should not be reduced as you have done it.  The wording of the problem is slightly ambiguous, allowing the cost of the ticket "for someone who buys a ticket" to potentially be treated as a sunken cost and have "expected value" apply only to potential winnings.  You seem to have the expected winnings correct, but either the cost of the ticket is $-13$ or is omitted (on the theory the ticket cost is in the past and forms no part of the outcome).

Comment: Indeed no; given back the cost of the ticket just means "don't deduct the 13 spent from the winnings it's given back" not "add an extra 13 on top"

Comment: Use `\$` to show the dollar sign. This site uses MathJax formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This question is poorly phrased.  I agree with the answers given. Other possible "correct" answers could be $1700/739$, and on the off chance that this is a terrible trick question, $1/739$.

Answer (score 1):

$E[X] = \frac{1713}{739} - 13 = -\$10.68$

This is because you are **always** putting in \$$13$, but get back \$$1713$ once in $739$ tries.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value of the act of buying a ticket is $-13(738/739) + 1700(1/739)\approx -10.68$ because the net for the winner is $1700$.  The expected value of a ticket is $1713/739\approx 2.32$ because now the cost of the ticket is not considered. I think the first is what is wanted.

Comment: I've put in all your answers, and still it saying the answer is wrong?

Comment: Your teacher is an 'it'?